# open source regression suite

Tags: linux, testing, open-source, regression-testing

I have a program, let's name it a.out, that reads input from a file and writes some output to stdout. For example a file contains the line
2,2
and my program "./a.out file" writes 4 at the screen.

Now in order to be sure that a.out works well after the patch, I am looking for a good regression suite for Linux. I want for every file that contains 2,2 my program to return 4 and I want this to be a test case.

Any ideas on regression packages?

Comment: Up-voted, good question, but its hard to suggest test cases without code. Does the function reading the file return a string / bool / etc?

Answer (score 1):

Have [a look at TAP](http://ccan.ozlabs.org/info/tap.html) for unit testing. Its what Perl uses for testing the innards of  Perl (specifically CPAN submissions), [CCAN](http://ccan.ozlabs.org) adopted it. I'm assuming C (you did say `a.out`). Then, simply make your read function fail if `2,2` is read (hinting on 3 bytes) if `NDEBUG` is not defined.

You could use something else, like `-DUNIT_TESTS_RUNNING`, just watch out for dependencies.

Then again, if the function you are testing returns a string .. no need to bother the preprocessor, let the test figure that out.

TAP is really, really easy to integrate. You can find my ad-hoc [Valgrind aware version here](http://echoreply.us/hg/nexgent.hg/index.cgi/file/dbbd5dab965c/src/tests). Note, that is not proper, that repo is a mess, but worth showing how easy it is to make other tools work with TAP.

Incidentally, TAP : (T)est (A)nything (P)rotocol

If this is NOT C, you need to re-tag your question.